# How to use a timer to see how long an equation takes in C#

Tags: c#, timer

In my program I'm trying to see how long it will take to calculate an amount of prime numbers

```
double time;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            bool isPrime = true;
            timer1.Start();
            for (int i = 2; i <= 200000; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j <= 200000; j++)
                {
                    if (i != j && i % j == 0)
                    {
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isPrime)
                {
                    //listBox1.Items.Add(i);
                }
                isPrime = true;
            }
            timer1.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show(time.ToString() + "ms");
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            time += 0.001; ;
        }
```

However when the program finishes calculating the messagebox displays time as zero.
I tested the program using the stopwatch class and that works, however I was wondering is there any way to use a timer instead?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend sticking with the [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2) class instead. `Timer` is really meant for reoccurring tasks, not measuring time.

Comment: If you are curious as to _why_ your `Timer` always shows `0`, it's because `Timer` is event based, and your tight loops never give the application a chance to process the timer's `Tick` events.  `Timer` is also notoriously inaccurate for small intervals like this.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you! I'll go back to using a stopwatch then.

Answer (score 0):

If this is purely academic:

```
myTimer.Interval = 1;
myTimer.Elapsed += IncrementEvent;
```

You could do the above to fire an event on each increment.

Causing the event to be fired every ~1ms.

```
public int incrementCounter {get; set; }
public void IncrementEvent()
{
    incrementCounter++;
}
```

I also believe you'd need to wire this up for multi-threading. (I can't remember the last time I used a timer, and never in a tight loop where locking would be a concern.

and then obviously use that value in your message box:

```
MessageBox.Show(incrementCounter.ToString() + "ms");
```

However, I'd argue to never use anything like this in production.

- You don't have much precision. 1ms is the smallest unit of time.
- The timer isn't very reliable. Even running it every few seconds, you'll see milliseconds of the time executed vary slightly.
- A timer is meant to schedule events to happen once t(ime) has ellapsed. There are much better tools for measuring how long an event takes.

Comment: Based on the code they have, they are using the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, rather than the `System.Threading.Timer`.  There shouldn't be any threading issues.